# Are botox injections approved by the FDA to treat chronic migrraines?

Tags: injections, migraine, wrinkles, fda

Obviously, botox injections are used to treat wrinkles. I've also heard that it can treat a panoply of other things, including overactive-bladders and migraine prevention!

Are botox injections FDA approved for migraine preventions? How does it work exactly? How long does it last? Where do they inject the botox? What are the possible risks?

Answer (score 3):

BOTOX is a prescription medicine that is injected into muscles and used to prevent (not treat) headaches in adults with chronic migraine who have 15 or more days each month with headache lasting 4 or more hours each day. It can prevent the next attack from occurring, but it isn't approved for treating an attack that someone is going through acutely, right now.

Botox is different than "Botox Cosmetic"

Ref: https://www.fda.gov/media/77359/download